# yum: gcc trying to install i686 architecture on x86_64 server

Tags: yum, x86

Trying to `YUM install gcc gcc-g++ make` and it fails with:

```
Package: glibc-2.17-260.el7.i686 (RHEL_SEC_7)
       Requires: glibc-common = 2.17-260.el7
       Installed: glibc-common-2.17-260.el7_6.3.x86_64 (@anaconda/7.6)
           glibc-common = 2.17-260.el7_6.3
       Available: glibc-common-2.17-55.el7.x86_64 (RHEL_SEC_7)
           glibc-common = 2.17-55.el7
       Available: glibc-common-2.17-55.el7_0.1.x86_64 (RHEL_SEC_7)
           glibc-common = 2.17-55.el7_0.1
       Available: glibc-common-2.17-55.el7_0.3.x86_64 (RHEL_SEC_7)
           glibc-common = 2.17-55.el7_0.3
       Available: glibc-common-2.17-55.el7_0.5.x86_64 (RHEL_SEC_7)
           glibc-common = 2.17-55.el7_0.5
       Available: glibc-common-2.17-78.el7.x86_64 (RHEL_SEC_7)
           glibc-common = 2.17-78.el7
       Available: glibc-common-2.17-105.el7.x86_64 (RHEL_SEC_7)
           glibc-common = 2.17-105.el7
       Available: glibc-common-2.17-106.el7_2.1.x86_64 (RHEL_SEC_7)
           glibc-common = 2.17-106.el7_2.1
       Available: glibc-common-2.17-106.el7_2.4.x86_64 (RHEL_SEC_7)
           glibc-common = 2.17-106.el7_2.4
       Available: glibc-common-2.17-106.el7_2.6.x86_64 (RHEL_SEC_7)
           glibc-common = 2.17-106.el7_2.6
       Available: glibc-common-2.17-106.el7_2.8.x86_64 (RHEL_SEC_7)
           glibc-common = 2.17-106.el7_2.8
       Available: glibc-common-2.17-157.el7.x86_64 (RHEL_SEC_7)
           glibc-common = 2.17-157.el7
       Available: glibc-common-2.17-157.el7_3.1.x86_64 (RHEL_SEC_7)
           glibc-common = 2.17-157.el7_3.1
       Available: glibc-common-2.17-157.el7_3.2.x86_64 (RHEL_SEC_7)
           glibc-common = 2.17-157.el7_3.2
       Available: glibc-common-2.17-157.el7_3.4.x86_64 (RHEL_SEC_7)
           glibc-common = 2.17-157.el7_3.4
       Available: glibc-common-2.17-157.el7_3.5.x86_64 (RHEL_SEC_7)
           glibc-common = 2.17-157.el7_3.5
       Available: glibc-common-2.17-196.el7.x86_64 (RHEL_SEC_7)
           glibc-common = 2.17-196.el7
       Available: glibc-common-2.17-196.el7_4.2.x86_64 (RHEL_SEC_7)
           glibc-common = 2.17-196.el7_4.2
       Available: glibc-common-2.17-222.el7.x86_64 (RHEL_7.6)
           glibc-common = 2.17-222.el7
       Available: glibc-common-2.17-260.el7.x86_64 (RHEL_SEC_7)
           glibc-common = 2.17-260.el7
```

However, output of
`yum list --showduplicates glibc` shows:

```
Installed Packages
glibc.x86_64                   2.17-260.el7_6.3                   @anaconda/7.6
```

and 
`yum list --showduplicates glibc-common`shows:

```
Installed Packages
glibc-common.x86_64               2.17-260.el7_6.3                @anaconda/7.6
```

A snippet of the output of `yum -v -y install gcc gcc-c++ make` shows:

```
Package glibc.i686 0:2.17-260.el7 will be installed
```

Why does yum try to mix architectures? How can I force yum to install only x86_64    dependencies?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `gcc` package is somewhat special, because the compiler in it can produce both 32-bit and 64-bit libraries. For that to work, it needs some basic i686 system libraries (`libgcc` and `glibc`). There's not much you can do about it, apart from recompiling the compiler to disable 32-bit support.

You'd better figure out why `glibc.i686` fails to install. Looks like a release mismatch, possibly due to an incompatible mix of repos (you have the `el7_6.3` release of `glibc-common` installed, but the `glibc.i686` package wants `el7`).